# Facebook - FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use Facebook javascript library function : FB.getLoginStatus.
This function works when the user is logged but fails when user is not logged to facebook.

Here is my code:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    console.log('entering the function!');
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            if (response.name != undefined) {
                console.log("Welcome, " + response.name);
            }
        });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log('not logged to app');
    } else {
        // NEVER POPUP
        console.log('user not logged');
    }
});
```

The last event (user not logged never popup), when a user is not logged, the function is not event firing and I do not see the log [entering the function].

Do someone has an idea to detect if a facebook user is connected.

Regards,
Linvi

Comment: same happens to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a bug report for this issue and Facebook developer reported that it was actually a current known issue.

Comment: Can you please share the link where you reported the issue on facebook platform ?